# How to close a XML FileStream

Tags: c#, .net, xml, memory-leaks, dispose

I'm using this code below to read .xml file & transfer data to 4 checkboxes. But im getting the error

**"The process cannot access the file: CXXXX Because its being used by another process"**

I thought it could be because the reading or writing, but closed both as you can see the code below. Any ideas?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists("data.xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
            FileStream read = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);

            data1.Text = info.Data1;
            data2.Text = info.Data2;
            data4.Text = info.Data3;
            data4.Text = info.Data4;

            read.Close();
        }
    }



// this class to write the data into xml file
class SaveXML
{
    public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
        sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
        writer.Close();        
    }
}


    // using this to update the .xml file with new data when textchanged
    private void data1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Information info = new Information();
            info.Data1 = data1.Text;
            SaveXML.SaveData(info, "data.xml");                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, so probably some other process has the file open? Based on your knowledge of your environment, do you know of any possible candidates for processes that might have it open?

Comment: You should wrap the file stream in a [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  See [using Statement (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).  Possibly the file was left open because an exception was thrown.

Comment: I agree with @1800INFORMATION.  But I would suggest closing the stream as soon as possible...right after the deserialization.

Comment: @dbc just like the guy showed below?

Comment: Yes.  It's not *certain* your problem is caused by a lack of a `using` statement.  But, it might be, and you should always wrap disposables in a `using` statement to ensure they are disposed in the event of an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make user you Dispose your Disposable objects to release references/memory and also it closes the underlying stream.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists("data.xml"))
        {
            using (FileStream read = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
           {
                XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information))
                Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);

                 data1.Text = info.Data1;
                 data2.Text = info.Data2;
                 data4.Text = info.Data3;
                 data4.Text = info.Data4;
          }
        }
    }


class SaveXML
{
    public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
    {
        using(TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

            sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }     
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If above didn't fix the error, probably Text Changed event(data1_TextChanged) fires too often. Try this functionality on TextBox LostFocus or with a button click event.

Comment: "The process cannot access the file: CXXXX Because its being used by another process"

Comment: @GabrielDeFreitas: Are you sure you made both of my above changes?

Comment: 100% sure, no idea whats going on

Comment: Probably Text Changed event(data1_TextChanged) fires too often. Try this functionality with a button click.

Comment: I was going to comment about it, just deleted the code and the errors were gone. Is there another way without needing to place a button for that?

Comment: @GabrielDeFreitas: Button is more appropriate I guess. However, other options are LostFocus of the TextBox.

Comment: @GabrielDeFreitas: Excellent !